# warning - assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, char

i got this warning " assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast "
(MARKED IN CODE PIECE) the code works fine, what i'm doing wrong and how can i fix this warning? thanx

````
 void Read_Keys(char *keys[MAX_LEN])  //Read the keys from input file 
{
    char c,Fname[MAX_LEN];

    gets(Fname);
    FILE *fptr = (fopen(Fname, "r")); // Input stream pointer assume

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("No Such File...");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(fptr) //if not empty get in
    {
        int i = 0;
        while((c = getc(fptr)) != EOF) //while loop copies each char from file
        {                             //to keys array
**          keys[i] = c; //          **                      WARNING IS HERE
            i++;
        }
        keys[i+1] = END; //ending point assume
    }
    fclose(fptr); //Close file for security issues
} ```
````

Comment: Never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's a [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function that have even been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Like the warning says, you are trying to write a single character to a pointer. The code cannot possibly work fine. `c` shouldn't even be `char` but `int`.

Comment: Also note that [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`** value, which is very crucial for that comparison to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: There is absolutely no way that this code works fine. You have just been lucky.

Comment: Lastly about your problem, is `keys` really supposed to be an *array of pointers* to `char` (i.e. an array of strings)? How do you use this function? What is it supposed to do? What is `END`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us how this function works in context.

Comment: How do you use/call this function, passing what and how is the latter defined.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, If the problem is answered/solved mark the answer if necessary. 
Please, Don't change the tile of the question to **solved, thanks for answering**. For people having the same problem, it's impossible for them to find this question by reading such headings. I have reverted  the question back to what it originally was

Answer (score 1):

The parameter keys is declared like

```
char *keys[MAX_LEN]
```

the compiler adjusts it to the following declaration

```
char **keys
```

So in this statement

```
keys[i] = c;
```

the left operand has the type `char *` that is it is a pointer while the right operand has the type `char`.

So the compiler issues a warning because this assignment does not make sense.

I suspect that in any case the parameter is declared incorrectly. It seems you mean the following declaration

```
void Read_Keys(char ( *keys )[MAX_LEN]);
```

that is you are trying to pass a two dimensional array to the function. But in any case this code snippet

```
    int i = 0;
    while((c = getc(fptr)) != EOF) //while loop copies each char from file
    {                             //to keys array
        keys[i] = c; //          **                      WARNING IS HERE
        i++;
    }
    keys[i+1] = END; //ending point assume
}
```

is invalid because it trues to write all the file in one record instead of an array of records.

Answer (score 0):

You `keys` parameter is an array of `MAX_LEN` pointers to `char`. So, if you want to assign a value inside this array, it should be a pointer to a character type. Here, `getc()` returns a character, not a pointer.

I think what you expect is `void Read_Keys(char *keys)`, with the following calling code:

```
char keys[MAX_LEN];

Read_Keys(keys);
```

Thus, your `keys` array is decayed into a `char *` pointer when `Read_Keys` is called. Inside `Read_Keys`, you can access all your array elements using an index, like `keys[2]`.

Obviously, you also need to pass you array length to `Read_Keys`, so the function knows which array index is valid and which one is not.